# pass data from js to php on the change of dropdown box

Tags: php

THE HTML IS FOLLOWING:

```
<form name="dataform">
<select name ="sel" onchange="go(dataform);">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

AND JS IS HERE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go(frm)
{
    if(frm.sel.value==1)
{
window.location="my.php?a="+frm;
}
}
</script>
```

AND THE PHP CODE IS HERE:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['a']))
{
    echo $_GET['a'];
}
?>
```

---

THE PROBLEM IS THAT, WHEN I ECHO $_GET['a'], IT GIVES HTMLFormELEMENT.
I WANT TO FORWARD THE PREVIOUS FORMDATA TO ANOTHER FORM. HOW COULD I GET THE PREVIOUS FORM ELEMENT.AND HOW TO FORWARD TO NEXT FORM WITHOUT POSTING A FORM......

Comment: WHY MUST WE TYPE OUR ENGLISH IN ALL CAPS, BUT CODE IN ALL LOWERCASE? (Just a FYI, typing in caps is perceived as screaming)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="dataform">
<select name ="sel" onchange="go(this);">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function go(ele)
{

window.location="my.php?a="+ele.value;

}
</script>
```